# Euler's theorem regarding Homogenous Functions

Tags: calculus

I am having trouble understanding the following theorem:
http://www.economics.utoronto.ca/osborne/MathTutorial/HOMF.HTM
aka "Eulers theorem for homogenous functions".

Why exactly do we need to take $t$ to be $t>0$ ... Isn't it enough to take $t\neq 0 $ ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess that this is the case to have domain always with positive coordinates.

Comment: But why do you have to have positive coordinates ? Thank !

Answer (score 1):

For $t<0$ and arbitrary $k$  the term $t^k$ can't be defined properly.

Comment: And why do you think we should take positive coordinates also  ? 
Thanks !